# Is anyone else experiancing a Syncfusion Pivot Grid remote data error?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, angular7, syncfusion

Typescript Version: 3.2.4
Angular version: ^7.2.15
Syncfusion Version: 17.1.50

Hi all. I am having an issue with Syncfusion's Pivot Grid. The code below is my onInit method which is taken straight from their demo. This was working as of 17.1.41 but now has magically stopped working. This issue is also on their [StackBlitz](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/demos/#/material/pivot-view/remote) example.

```js
ngOnInit() {
    let data: DataManager;
    data = new DataManager({
      url: this._controllerUrl + "/billing/extract",
      adaptor: new WebApiAdaptor(),
      crossDomain: true,
      headers: [
        {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Accept: "application/json",
          Authorization: "Bearer " + this.token
        }
      ]
    });

    this.dataSource = {
      enableSorting: true,
      columns: [{ name: "Year" }, { name: "Month" }],
      values: [{ name: "Cost", caption: "Cost (GBP)" }],
      data: data,
      rows: [{ name: "ServiceId" }],
      formatSettings: [],
      expandAll: false,
      filters: []
    };
    this.button = new Button({ isPrimary: true });
    this.button.appendTo("#export");

    this.button.element.onclick = (): void => {
      this.pivotGridObj.excelExport();
    };
  }
```

Here is the full error in Firefox:

```
ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.parent.dataSource.values is undefined
./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-pivotview/src/common/grouping-bar/axis-field-renderer.js/AxisFields.prototype.createPivotButtons@http://localhost:4200/views-billing-billing-module.js:197167:17
./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-pivotview/src/common/grouping-bar/axis-field-renderer.js/AxisFields.prototype.render@http://localhost:4200/views-billing-billing-module.js:197143:14
./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-pivotview/src/common/grouping-bar/grouping-bar.js/GroupingBar.prototype.appendToElement@http://localhost:4200/views-billing-billing-module.js:197347:49
./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-base/src/observer.js/Observer.prototype.notify@http://localhost:4200/views-billing-billing-module.js:10781:25
./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-base/src/component.js/Component.prototype.notify@http://localhost:4200/views-billing-billing-module.js:5505:32
./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-pivotview/src/pivotview/base/pivotview.js/PivotView.prototype.renderPivotGrid@http://localhost:4200/views-billing-billing-module.js:204990:18
./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-base/src/observer.js/Observer.prototype.notify@http://localhost:4200/views-billing-billing-module.js:10781:25
./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-base/src/component.js/Component.prototype.notify@http://localhost:4200/views-billing-billing-module.js:5505:32
./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-pivotview/src/pivotview/base/pivotview.js/PivotView.prototype.initEngine@http://localhost:4200/views-billing-billing-module.js:206000:14
./node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-pivotview/src/pivotview/base/pivotview.js/PivotView.prototype.executeQuery@http://localhost:4200/views-billing-billing-module.js:206047:14
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7688:26
onInvoke@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:82616:33
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7687:52
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</Zone.prototype.run@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7447:43
scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:8186:34
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7720:31
onInvokeTask@http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:82607:33
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7719:60
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7492:47
drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7898:35
./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js/</ZoneTask.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:7799:21
invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9041:14
globalZoneAwareCallback@http://localhost:4200/polyfills.js:9067:17
```

Here is the full error in Chrome/Edge

```
core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at AxisFields.push../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-pivotview/src/common/grouping-bar/axis-field-renderer.js.AxisFields.createPivotButtons (axis-field-renderer.js:45)
    at AxisFields.push../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-pivotview/src/common/grouping-bar/axis-field-renderer.js.AxisFields.render (axis-field-renderer.js:21)
    at GroupingBar.push../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-pivotview/src/common/grouping-bar/grouping-bar.js.GroupingBar.appendToElement (grouping-bar.js:142)
    at Observer.push../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-base/src/observer.js.Observer.notify (observer.js:89)
    at PivotViewComponent.push../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-base/src/component.js.Component.notify (component.js:188)
    at PivotViewComponent.push../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-pivotview/src/pivotview/base/pivotview.js.PivotView.renderPivotGrid (pivotview.js:881)
    at Observer.push../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-base/src/observer.js.Observer.notify (observer.js:89)
    at PivotViewComponent.push../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-base/src/component.js.Component.notify (component.js:188)
    at PivotViewComponent.push../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-pivotview/src/pivotview/base/pivotview.js.PivotView.initEngine (pivotview.js:1891)
    at PivotViewComponent.push../node_modules/@syncfusion/ej2-pivotview/src/pivotview/base/pivotview.js.PivotView.executeQuery (pivotview.js:1938)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at zone.js:896
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17290)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:502)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1744)
    at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1770)
```

The weird thing about this, is that if I use a subset of the data that is coming back from the server and set it locally, it all works.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22890.png) is an image of the request that I am making with the response and the data. I'm not sure if this is something that I can fix as this may be a bug with the `DataManager`.

I have tried reverting back to the previous version that I used, but there still seems to be the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

We are glad to announce that our Essential Studio 2019 Volume 2 Beta Release version 17.2.0.28 is rolled out with the mentioned issue fix and is available for download under the following link.

https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/145548/essential-studio-2019-volume-2-beta-release-v17-2-0-28-is-available-for-download

Note: This issue fix will be included in our main release as well which is expected to be available by mid of July 2019.

We thank you for your support and appreciate your patience in waiting for this release. Please get in touch with us if you would require any further assistance.

Regards,
Dinesh Babu Yadav